# Prove that Nth prime number is bigger or equal than 3n

Tags: prime-numbers, induction

Let $P_{n}$ be the nth prime number. Prove that $\forall n \in N, n \ge 12: P_{n} > 3n$. Tried to use induction here but couldn't get any reasonable relation between $P_{n}$ and $P_{n+1}$.

Comment: I would suspect this to be quite difficult (might be wrong though) - the gaps between primes become arbitrarily large. What is the source of this question?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: instead of looking at one prime following $P_n$ look at two. How big is the minimum gap to the second prime?

Comment: Isn't that just two? Perhaps I have misunderstood

Comment: @AnotherJohnDoe No, I meant count two primes after $P_n$., and of course the premise is that $P_n$ is sufficiently large.